# 3 string arrays in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I have in C# 3 string arrays

```
string[] ARRAY1 = {HELLO 1, HELLO2 ,...}
string[] ARRAY2 = {COOKIE 1, COOKIE 2,...}
string[] ARRAY3 = {C# 1, C# 2,...}
```

I want to show them in a DataGridView like this
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJKjf.png)

How do I do it?
I was trying around but it never looked like the picture (It's my first time using DataGridViews).
Hope somebody will help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have only 3 arrays, you can [add the columns](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwii0vDU4-n0AhXc6XMBHcwYBuMQFnoECA0QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fdesktop%2Fwinforms%2Fcontrols%2Fadd-and-remove-columns-in-the-datagrid-using-the-designer&usg=AOvVaw3aDoZce4KKACNh2pa4fDJJ) manually in the designer.
If you want to do it in code:

```cs
yourDataGridView.Columns.Add("yourColumnName", "theHeaderText");
```

and if you want to add rows (the index is depending on ARRAY1's length)

```cs
string[] ARRAY1 = {"HELLO 1", "HELLO 2"};
string[] ARRAY2 = {"COOKIE 1", "COOKIE 2"};
string[] ARRAY3 = {"C# 1", "C# 2"};
public void AddArraysToDataGridView ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY1.Length; i++)
    {
        yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(i, ARRAY1[i], ARRAY2[i], ARRAY3[i]);
    }
}
```

If you want to add that just call the `AddArraysToDataGridView ()` function.
Here's the result (I have no idea how to remove the first column.)
[image: The result]